# Filtering Select Result in join query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two tables, tblA, and tblB, these two tables joind each other on a field, in tblB I have a field thats name is X, i want to filter my select result based on X value, how I can do this?
best regards.

Comment: Could you provide the query you are currently using? Also, do you want to filter before the two tables join or after the join?

Comment: Can you please explain it more with a sample?

Comment: I don't use any query, but I want to filter tables after join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tblA.field1, tblA.field2, tblB.field1, tblB.field2, tblB.X
FROM tblA
LEFT JOIN tblB
   ON tblA.ID=tblB.FKofTblAID
WHERE tblB.X = 'SomeValue'
```

Comment: tnx, but maybe I don't explaine my problem carefully, this is my mistake. ex: tblA contains idA, nameA, FNo and tblB containes idB,nameB,Fno,Type and ... .If Type is 0 or 1 the select results are diffrent, how can I manage this? I want to return result in only one cursor.

Comment: Rojin - it isn't clear why John's answer will not work for you from what you say in your comment, other than you need to change the field names to match your names, and the WHERE clause at the end will now be something like "WHERE tblB.Type = 0" or "WHERE tblB.Type = 1" depending on which set of types you are interested in. If that won't work, please add some sample data to the question and explain what results you want to get, to give people a chance to give you an answer that satisfies you.